# Handle json object with php and push it to .js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have this function on the client-side

```
function ajaxPost(obj){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url to the php file",//I'm not sure about this line
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        dataType: 'json'    
        });
}
```

and this php on server-side

```
<?php 
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

?>
```

I'm calling `ajaxPost` function on button click from client side. So when i call the function php on the server puts the json object inside `$json` variable.
How to paste this json object to existing .js file on the server while replacing previous code inside .js file.

So the object send from the client side must replace already existing .js content.
So what im trying is to change the script inside this .js file on the server with the passed object from the client

To clearify im using this .js file on the server as an API that i call from the client side every minute but i want to be able to change its content from an admin panel

Comment: What? You want to POST something to a .JS file, which PHP cant interpret (without special treatment) ?

Comment: I'm new to php and server-side scripting at all but yeah i want to manipulate .js file on the server which .js file clients get with ajax request

Comment: Tricky. First of all, you should POST that to a .php file. Within that .php file you can replace content of any file on your file system. As for the frontend, it wont care what you did to that .js file, because its probably already in the DOM. You need to find a way to tell the frontend "hey, theres new content in my file, please reload the file".

Comment: im doing it with every minute with ajax request via setinterval js method.
Im calling ajaxPost function on button click from control.html which only the admin can open

Comment: see the update paskl

Comment: My thoughts: Find a way to not cache this file server and client side. In your admin form, POST your data to another .php file. This file changes the content of the .js file and invalidates the old one (if possible). Next time the client asks the .js file it'll see the new data.

Comment: yes this is what i want but i dont know how to change the content of the .js file with php and what do you mean with 'invalidtes the old one'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109215/discussion-between-paskl-and-georgi-antonov).